# Clear previous Activities from the widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

First i load my application which starts activity A then i go to Activity B. Then press my home button and load Widget. Clicking the button in the widget loads an Activity XXXX which is a class inside the application ,

```
Intent searchDailog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                      .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                      .setComponent(new ComponentName("com.af.screenmanager",
                                    "com.af.screenmanager.XXXX"));

searchDailog.putExtra("ID", appWidgetIds);
searchDailog.putExtra("View", remoteViews);
searchDailog.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

searchDailog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(context, 0, searchDailog,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_search_btn,
                    configPendingIntent);
```

This works fine, ie the "XXXX" class loads.

But the problem is, from here when i press the back button the "XXXX" Activity closes and shows the Activity B (screen from where i pressed home button). I dont want to view this, instead it must go to home screen.

I think the loaded A and B activities are there in the Activity stack. So how could i clear the stack from the widget.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i figure out my prblm. Since my "XXXX" class Activity is in the same application package it will load in the same application stack. ie, it will load above the previous activity.

By putting

```
android:taskAffinity="af.searchActivity"
```

in the manifest of "XXXX" class causes the activity to load in a separate stack.

This one helps me.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff

Comment: i do think that this solution is overly complex. just learn to manage effectively your activity stack! you don't need more stacks in your case.

Comment: i know this is complex. the app works fine. I have done lots of googling, but this soln fixed my query..

Answer (score 0):

when you launch a new activity (i.e. Act1) from another activity (i.e. ActZ) and you do not want that ActZ returns when Act1 closes, just add this:

```
ActZ.finish();
```

after you launch the Act1.

This way, when Act1 ends (back button pressed is a prime example) the activity which gets resumed is not ActZ for sure, but the one which called ActZ (like your home screen)

Comment: In my application i want to navigate back and forth....so dont want to finish. I want to clear all screens when i go from widget

Comment: finish() will close the middle activity (in your example), not you application. when you need to go forth and reopen the middle activity, it will be recreated and terminated when you go a step forward, so when you go back 1 step you will be at your home screen

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. When I was clicking a button from the widget, it doesn't create a single page. My activity stack is not empty.

Finally, I have put this single line in manifest file within an activity tag, then it works fine.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```